# Exiting a blocking read in python - do I need to work around it?

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduler, can-bus

I am the author of a Python [module that implement the IsoTP protocol](https://github.com/pylessard/python-can-isotp), an automotive half-duplex protocol that generally runs over CAN (ISO-15765). The protocol basically segment a long frame in many small CAN messages. The sender and the receiver also exchange some control messages, the role of CAN sender/receiver swap constantly (because of half-duplex).

The first version of my project only implemented the protocol logic and let the problem of timing handling to the user who could simply calls run something like

```py
proto.send(...)
while proto.is_transmitting():
    proto.process()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

To achieve that, it was required that the CAN layer be configured in non-blocking read. This technique was very simple and was good enough in a lot of cases. Obvious drawback is that timings are not very good and it causes issues for people who needs to transfer lot of data, generally to flash an ECU over CAN. The sleep method would add a time slice delay between each change of transmission direction.

I have improved that. I now run the logic in a thread, using a python `Queue` to interact with the user thread. The CAN layer is now expected to do blocking read. I have achieved very good timings when comes to switch direction because of control messages. I am left with a problem for which I cannot find a solution that I really like.

Essentially, when the user calls `send()`. I write the payload to a `Queue` object. The working thread reads that queue and starts its logic relying on the CAN blocking read to release the CPU during the transmission of a CAN frame (~230us per message generally). The issue I have is as follow; when a frame is receive (not a message, a full isotp frame), if there is no data in the user transmit queue, the only logical thing to do is do a blocking read, in case somebody starts a transmission. Very often, the user will send a new frame right after receiving one, requiring the blocking read to timeout before the worker thread sees the new user data.

At high level it often goes roughly like that:

```py
cursor=0
chunk_size=128
while cursor < len(firmware):
    proto.send(firmware[cursor:cursor+chunk_size])    # write to the tx queue
    response = proto.recv(timeout=2)       # wait for the thread to write to the rx queue
    if not response.accepted:
        raise RuntimeError("Flashing failed")
    cursor+=chunk_size
```

See how the next message is queued only after the previous response has been received? That delay is enough to put the worker thread in a blocking read state, which will timeout eventually, say after a time slice of 16ms (Windows typical) and the the transmission will start.

That 16ms delay can be a problem. Imagine a 1MiB payload, sent in chunk of 128 bytes: we have 8192 time slices: which can be 131 seconds . That is a lot of wasted time.

The solution I see are:

1. Ask the user to enqueue more than 1 chunks in the queue and cancel the transmission if one chunk is nacked by the ECU. I guess this is the most obvious solution
2. I can add a spinwait after a frame is received, leaving a window of time where the user thread can enqueue the enxt payload. That works, but waste CPU time.
3. I could possibly split my protocol logic into 2 thread (1 for Tx and 1 for Rx). That will require lot of synchronization mechanism between thos 2 internal thread adding lot of complexity that I'd like to avoid.
4. I could have a 2 threads. 1 is the worker thread, same as before. But I could replace the CAN layer blocking read by a blocking read on a 2nd queue fed by a 2nd thread that simply transfer anything it reads to the queue. I know that Python is able to do a fast context switch in that case, I haven't checked the details, but I suspect condition variables to be used under the hood. Python can switch context in ~20us on both Linux and Windows using a blocking read on a `Queue`.  By doing that, the user `send()` method could inject a "wakeup" object that would be identified by its type (not being a bytes/None) and then discarded by the logic.  This solution is my best candidate so far.

The ideal scenario would be if I could send a signal to cancel the blocking read like Unix supports natively but I'm not sure if I have access to portable custom signals in python. And on top of that, the users have the flexibility to change the link layer (CAN) read function; maybe this function does not like signals at all!

Is there anything else I can do to interrupt that blocking read and improve the transmit timing ?

See the following diagram. The goal is to eliminate the delay in red.

[image]

Comment: Can you avoid the blocking read by blocking in `select()` instead?  The nice thing about `select()` is that you can set it to watch more than one socket at a time, which means that if you need to wake a `select()` call up from another thread, you can have the `select()` call block (waiting for bytes-ready-to-read) on the receiving end of a pipe (or socketpair), in addition to your usual socket, and then another thread can cause `select()` to return at any time simply by writing a byte to the sending end of the pipe/socketpair.

Comment: that'd be exactly the behavior I need.  select is Unix specific right? And also, the access to the link layer (the CAN layer) is a user callback because it could call a DLL, an emulator, a socket, or python-can...  I guess with that being unknown, my options are reduced.  Unless I support what I can and document that the timings are better on Linux when the rxfn meet some requirements.  (So far, option #4 gives good results)

Comment: select() works in every POSIX OS and under Windows as well (although its behavior is slightly different under Windows, but not in any way that I think you'd notice for this use-case).